# Regular expression for htaccess URL rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

hiii ,

I want to rewrite the directory www.mysite.com/index.php?category=news
to www.mysite.com/news
I write this code but its doesn't work
anyone can help, please
thanks for help

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule  ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ index.php?category=$1
```

Thanks for all who answered my question , all the codes are work when i try to write  www.mysite.com/news , but I mean when i click on a link 
"a href='index.php?category=news'"link"/a" I want to be rewrite to www.mysite.com/news immediately

Comment: What happens when you go to http://www.mysite.com/news?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you mean "rewrite `news` to `index.php?category=news`" and not the other way around

Comment: levi Morrison , its works  but I mean when i click on a link "a href='index.php?category=news'"link"/a" I want to be rewrite to www.mysite.com/news immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to confirm, the pattern you want to match is all letters, numbers, hyphens and forward-slashes, right?

If so, try this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)$ index.php?category=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I think the problem may have been your ordering of the hyphen and forward-slash in the character class expression. To match hyphens, they should appear first or last in the set of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?category=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule news/ index.php?category=news
RewriteRule news index.php?category=news
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(news|or|some|other|category)$ index.php?category=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```